# Issue getting DLL handle using process explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, process

I am trying to see how a certain section of Windows is "built", more specifically the interaction between winlogon.exe, msgina.dll and keymgr.dll

When I launch Process Explorer or Dependancy Walker I simply do not see Key Manager anywhere which is confusing to me.

Winlogon is always started in the following thread: 'NT_AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.

The part of Key Manager I'm looking at is the 'Forgotten Password Wizard' that is linked to the 'Windows Security' dialog box. I have checked Key Manager and the wizard is definetley in that file. However when I run the wizard there is no sign of Key Manager in process explorer.

Nor is it in any process that I open in depencancy walker. (smaa, csrss, lsass, services, dllhost, svchost, alg, winlogon).

Any ideas why it is not showing up? It might be running as Rundll32 but it is not showing up in proccess explorer and Rundll32 is not usually used in such a high privileged thread.

For the record does anybody happen know what the DLL handle is to save me fighting with process explorer to get it to show it.

Answer (score 0):

The "Forgotten Password Wizard" can be activated by running the following from the Run dialog:

```
RunDll32.exe keymgr.dll,PRShowSaveWizardExW
```

So, yes it is activated via `RunDll32.exe`.

Comment: This command works fine however sometimes (very often) windows uses direct api calls instead of using rundll to call PRShowSaveWizardExW. For example Winlogon or msgina might just do it.

Comment: Yes, this is very possible.  Besides `PRShowSaveWizardExW`, keymgr.dll also exports the functions:  `PRShowSaveFromMsginaW` and `PRShowRestoreFromMsginaW` among other, so it would make sense that msgina is directly accessing the API.  What exactly are you trying to determine? Are you trying to tell  which process is hosting the Forgotten password UI?

Comment: Also, depwalker is not necessarily going to help you.  It will not show libraries that are loaded via `GetProcAddress` unless you are profiling the process.  This may be something you have to discover at runtime.

Comment: Those function names indicate that they are interned to be called from msgina.

Comment: when I click profile it profiles but then stops so there is not enough time to open the windows security dialog and open the forgotten password wizard, so that depwalker will see keymgr (which it currently does not)